# PHP/MySQL full file name instead of grabbing from ID

Tags: php, mysql, seo

I've been wondering for quite a while how do you set up php so that you instead of getting content from tables w/ get like www.mysite.com/index.php?id=1 you get them by www.mysite.com/pages/news-1.php

I have no idea how else to make up this question; but do I have to manually create new pages and put them in directories then link the page/ID via db or is there another way with mysql only.

Comment: I may be wrong here but that may just be pretty URLs using .htaccess.

Comment: Use your favourite search engine on the term "url rewriting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file with name **.htaccess** in your web root directory. And paste these lines into it (*Tested*):

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine    
RewriteRule    ^pages/news-([0-9]+)/?$     index.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

> **URL rewriting** can be one of the best and quickest ways to improve the
>   usability and search friendliness of your site. It can also be the
>   source of near-unending misery and suffering. Definitely worth playing
>   carefully with it - lots of testing is recommended. With great power
>   comes great responsibility, and all that. *Aug 4, 2008 - addedbytes.com*

Answer (score 0):

With URL rewriting, you need to route all page requests to your "front controller" / index.php. Then you use a router to send that request to a particular controller method. In that method, you would grab the request's path (eg. /postname). Your posts database table would have a "slug" field. You then query the database for the "posts" result that contains the slug "postname".

Please check out this tutorial to learn how to make a custom framework, it'll give you the amount of background information that might shed some light on how this all works: http://symfony.com/doc/master/create_framework/index.html